# Convert instanced object to string

Tags: java, string, object

I initialize a Password object and I am having trouble using the same object as a string for later purposes like counting the amount of letters in the string. I know that I'm only getting the textual representation of the object with the methods *String.valueOf* and *.toString*. How do I go about taking the my object pass and getting the "hello" string I initialized it with?

```
public class Password {

public Password (String text) {
}

public String getText(){
    String string = String.valueOf(this);
    return string;
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Password pass = new Password ("hello");
    System.out.println(pass.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: override the `toString()` method and return the value that you want.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual `getText()` method doesn't make sense :

```
public String getText(){
    String string = String.valueOf(this);
    return string;
}
```

You try to recreate a `String` from  the `toString()` method of the `Password` instance.
It is really not necessary (useless computation) and it is clumsy as `toString()` is not designed to provide a functional data.

To reach your goal, it is very basic.

Store the text in a field of the `Password` instance :

```
public Password (String text) {
  this.text = text;
}
```

And provide a view on the `text` field.

You could replace `getText()` in this way :

```
public String getText(){    
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fields.

```
public class Password {

    private String text; // This is a member (field) It belongs to each
                             // Password instance you create.

    public Password(String value) {
        this.text = value; // Copy the reference to the text to the field
                           // 'text'
    }
}
```

The problem with `String.valueOf(this)`, where `this` is a `Password` instance, is that the `valueOf()` method has absolutely no idea of how to convert a `Password` instance to a field`. You named it "Password", but it could also be`MyText`or`MySecret`. So you need to tell how a`Password`instance can be displayed as text. In your case, you'll need to just use the`text` field from the abovementioned example.

You should definitely read the [docs about classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html). I think you're missing something basic.

---

*Note: You should also never store a password into a String, because of security implications, but that's a whole other story, and beyond the scope of your question.*